# How to insert multiple array with sub array as rows in Mysql using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with following field id, name, type and color

I have following input fields and want to add multiple rows

```
<input type="text" name="com_name[]" value="a">
<input type="text" name="com_type[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="com_color[]" value="red">
<input type="text" name="com_type[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="com_color[]" value="green">

<input type="text" name="com_name[]" value="b">
<input type="text" name="com_type[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="com_color[]" value="black">
<input type="text" name="com_type[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="com_color[]" value="yellow">
```

I am trying laravel but if some can show how to do it in core PHP that would  also be great help

```
$com_name = array();
$com_name = Input::get('com_name');
$dataSet = [];
foreach ($com_name as $name) {
    $dataSet[] = [
        'name'  => $request->com_name,
        'type'    => $request->com_type,
        'color'       => $request->com_color,
    ];
}

DB::table('extra')->insert($dataSet);
```

I want the following output in my mysql table

```
ID  Name  Type  Color
1    a     1     red
2    a     2     green
3    b     1     black
4    b     2     yellow
```

Comment: In your loop, in addition to getting the value, also get the index (`as $i => $name`). Then you can apply that same index to the other arrays to get the corresponding values for them.

Comment: Thaks but could you please write the full code

Comment: My question is little diffrent, I have 2 set of name a,b with 2 sub set of each name

Comment: Are the values for all of the inputs editable? Your current HTML makes it look like they are.  Is that a paste of the actual rendered HTML?

Comment: yes value is editable, My html has dynamic inputs fields
I have html like this we have multiple com_name with sub inputs [type] and [color] and we can add unlimited type and color within each com_name

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating sub-arrays in your HTML with explicit top-level indexes like this ...

```
<input type="text" name="com_name[0]" value="a">
<input type="text" name="com_type[0][]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="com_color[0][]" value="red">
<input type="text" name="com_type[0][]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="com_color[0][]" value="green">

<input type="text" name="com_name[1]" value="b">
<input type="text" name="com_type[1][]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="com_color[1][]" value="black">
<input type="text" name="com_type[1][]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="com_color[1][]" value="yellow">
```

Then in your PHP you'll loop through those sub-arrays with a second foreach ...

```
foreach ($com_name as $index => $value) {
    $type = $request->com_type[$index];

    foreach($type as $subIndex => $typeVal)
    {
        $dataSet[] = [
            'name'  => $value,
            'type'    => $typeVal,
            'color'       => $request->com_color[$index][$subIndex],
        ];
    }
}
```

I don't use Laravel personally, so this assumes that your Laravel-specific code that you have above is correct.